# Show the centralizer of H in G is a subgroup of the normalizer of H in G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.  Prove that $C_G(H)<N_G(H)$.

Missed the discussion on normalizer and centralizer.  I just have the definitions:
$$N_G(H)=\{g\in G\mid gHg^{-1}=H\}$$
$$C_G(H)=\{g\in G\mid gh=hg, \forall h\in H\}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in C_G(H)$ then $xH=Hx$.

So $xHx^{-1}=H$.

Hence $x\in N_G(H)$.

Comment: Well, that is simple.  I think I was looking way too into this question.

Comment: no problem my friend